# Support for C# 9.0 in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

How can I turn on the support for the records keyword in C# 9.0?

When I try to use the new `record` keyword (or the `init`), I get an ***unexpected token*** error in Visual Studio.

What am I missing? Or is C# 9.0 not supported in Visual Studio 16.8?

```cs
public record Person
{
    public string? FirstName { get; init; }
    public string? LastName { get; init; }
}
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

---

> **Update**: Just read the marked answer. The information below ended up not being important for this problem and is here just for documentation purposes.

---

I am using Visual Studio 16.8 with the language set to `9.0` in my project file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer" Version="3.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.9">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

#### Visual Studio Version

[image: Visual Studio Version]

#### Installed SDKs

```sh
2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.508 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

#### Proof that it's running .NET 5.

So to make sure it's really running .NET 5, I have created a route to output the .NET runtime version. Looks like it's really running .NET 5.

[image]

Comment: C# 9.0 require [.Net 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) and to run it you need Visual Studio **2019** Version 16.8 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core)). Typo?

Comment: No repro. C# 9 is used by default with .NET 5 RTM, in VS 16.8 (and most of the previews). What VS version and SDK version are you using?

Comment: BTW post the *code*, not images of the code. Images can't be copied and compiled. As for using `string?` you do understand that if you store a `null` there you won't be able to replace it? Are you trying to use `Person` with an ORM perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I post the code, someone will say I copied it wrong and have a typo. If I make a screenshot, someone will say post the code ;).
Give me a few seconds and I will do both.

Comment: I'm downvoting because the question contains images instead of actual text, making it impossible to investigate the problem

Comment: Up in the upper-right corner of your "About Visual Studio" details page, it says you are using .NET Framework 4.8.  You need .NET 5.  Have you installed that?  Please don't paste in pictures of code or other text.  Paste it in as text (and format it as code)

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, I think that's the version Visual Studio is running on. But as you can see in my CSPROJ, the Target Framework is set to NET 5.0.

Comment: For older frameworks it was `<TargetFrameworkVersion>`, was it changed? Another stupid question: is it C# project?

Comment: @Sinatr yes, it's a project that was running .NET Core 3.1 until a few hours ago. I switched it to run with .NET 5.0 and everything works fine (had some Unit Tests failing when we migrated, but everything is fixed now). The only thing that is not working is the new C# 9.0 syntax. I believe, it used to work in the Preview version of Visual Studio 2019. I was thinking, maybe something went wrong with the release of Visual Studio 16.8 yesterday and thus the question to find out if anyone else is facing the same issues.

Comment: So I'm coming to conclusion that it's probably a bug in Visual Studio...

Comment: <TargetFrameworkVersion> is still right. I've update one of my existing projects and created a new one and both projects do not have issues with the syntacs. Maybe try to reinstall or repair your VS installation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After analyzing the loading times of the error message and receiving the same error message in the Rider IDE, I came to conclusion it had to be Resharper.

I uninstalled Resharper and the error messages disappeared.

---

## Update

Resharper 2020.3 and [Rider 2020.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/whatsnew/) are released now and officially support .NET 5 and C# 9.

Comment: In Visual Studio, there was an Error `unexpected token`. I don't remember if it also appeared in the Build Errors. When I built the application using the `dotnet` CLI, it built (and ran) successfully, which proved there is no syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I was having the same issue and hadn't thought of Resharper as the cause. Who'd have thought they wouldn't support c# 9 at its release? Anyhow, I moved to the Early Access Program (#7) and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [ReSharper 2020.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/download-thanks.html?code=RSU&platform=windows) for it to work with .NET 5 and C# 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to target the .Net 5 framework.

> C# 9.0 is supported on .NET 5. For more information, see C# language versioning.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9

Comment: I did, it compiles otherwise

Comment: @ElMac but that's the answer. If you target .NET 5, you get C# 9 by default. If you have issues, you may be using the wrong VS version and/or using a pre-release version of .NET 5

Comment: @PeterBons The Target Framework is set in my CSPROJ File. I believe it's set correctly?

Comment: @PeterBons I haven't updated the ASP.NET Core dependencies to 5.0 yet, but I believe that should be no issue - right?

Comment: @ElMac the framework dependencies like Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and \Microsoft.NETCore.App should refer to .Net 5.